# Верстка иконок с генерацией через each в Pug

Tags: html, веб-программирование, вёрстка, pug

Всем привет. В чем собственно проблема. Мне нужно сверстать 4 иконки в ряд. Причем нужно использовать Font Awesome. Вообщем, я создал цикл each с переменной **social** для создания элементов списка, но когда я хочу сгенерировать для каждого элемента списка по одному классу, то генерируется по 4 элемента в каждом списке. тоесть получается.`

```html
<ul class="socials">
          <li class="social__icon_fb">
            <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
            <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
            <i class="fab fa-skype"></i>
            <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
          </li>
          <li class="social__icon_tw">
            <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
            <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
            <i class="fab fa-skype"></i>
            <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
          </li>
          <li class="social__icon_skype">
            <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
            <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
            <i class="fab fa-skype"></i>
            <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
          </li>
          <li class="social__icon_in">
            <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
            <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
            <i class="fab fa-skype"></i>
            <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
          </li>
```

`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы делаете лишний цикл - https://codepen.io/DmitriyShvanyk/pen/xxwLxrB

Comment: Но в Вашем примере, класс для иконки Font Awesome, и для элемента списка одинаковый. Вариант рабочий, но эстетически не красив, и не очень подходит под БЭМ методологию, потому что правила наименования классов Font Awesome и БЭМ-нейминга немного расходятся. По этому я хотел бы, что бы элементы списка имели свой бэм-класс.

Comment: почему мой вариант не подходит по бэм? вы открывали доки по бэм?

Comment: также не понятно, что означает - эстетически не красив?